# Как переместить строку на уровень выше в dataGridView

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

У меня такая проблема: требуется по нажатию кнопки переместить текущую записи, к примеру, с 3 третьей строки на вторую и наоборот. Как это возможно реализовать, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 3):

На сколько я помню, у `DataGridViewRowCollection` нет метода `Move`. Поэтому можно поступить так: пусть `row` - это наша строка, которую мы будем двигать, а `dgv` - это наш `DataGridView`. Так же у нас будет переменная `offset`, которая будет задавать смещение (-1 если двигаем строку вверх, 1 - если вниз)

```
// Здесь мы проверяем можно ли двиать строку -- если она первая, то вверх мы ее 
// двигать не можем. Так же не можем двигать последнюю строку вниз, а так же мы не
// можем двиать "новую строку" - это которая `Placeholder-строка` (если она есть
// конечно, но будем считать, что есть)
if (row.Index == 0 && offset == -1 || ((row.Index == dgv.NewRowIndex - 1) &&
    offset == 1 || row.Index == dgv.NewRowIndex)
  return; // Ничего делать не надо => выходим
// Получаем текущий индекс строки
int currentIndex = row.Index;
// Удаляем ее из коллекции
dgv.Rows.Remove(row);
// А теперь добавляем со смещением
dgv.Rows.Insert(currentIndex + offset, row);
```

Answer (score 2):

Примерный алгоритм.

1. Получаем и сохраняем индекс выбранной строки.
2. Сохраняем данные строки.
3. Получаем данные из индекс - 1 и заменяем их в нашей строке.
4. Вставляем наши сохранённые данные в индекс - 1.